# How may I stack multiple html/css buttons vertically along the center of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My css is listed below, followed by the html.

I am not currently aware of a method to centralize the buttons within the below detailed "box/inner-box" s. The flex display seems to be stacking the buttons vertically (though, honestly, I am not certain as to how), but, no matter what I try, and I have tried most searchable recommendations, I cannot seem to locate the column of buttons to the centre of the page, beneath the 'my name' . Does anyone know how I might centralize the buttons or if there is a much simpler method for accomplishing a similar aesthetic? I am open to all solutions. Thank you in advance!

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.box .box-inner {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 40px;
}

.btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 400;
}
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  color: #000000;
  outline: 0;
}

.me {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.me:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.cv {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.cv:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.rd {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.rd:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.av {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.av:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.rr {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.rr:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}
```

```html
    <body>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='box-inner'>
            <h1>myname</h1>
            <button class="btn me">me</button>
            <button class="btn cv">cv</button>
            <button class="btn rd">rd</button>
            <button class="btn av">av</button>
            <button class="btn rr">rr</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: How about `text-align : center` ?

Comment: @liamwilt Did you try the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you already have multiple answers. However the way you use flex is not correct. It should be added into the parent div `box-inner`

```
  display:flex;
  align-items:center; //align item center
  flex-direction:column; //direction to column
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.box .box-inner {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 40px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 400;
}
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  color: #000000;
  outline: 0;
}

.me {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.me:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.cv {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.cv:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.rd {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.rd:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.av {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.av:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.rr {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.rr:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}
```

```html
    <body>
      <div class='box'>
        <div class='box-inner'>
            <h1>myname</h1>
            <button class="btn me">me</button>
            <button class="btn cv">cv</button>
            <button class="btn rd">rd</button>
            <button class="btn av">av</button>
            <button class="btn rr">rr</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: brilliant. exactly what was missing. i figured there might be a misplaced style here or there, but i wasn't entirely sure. i had actually attempted to use those exact elements before, but it was either on the 'html/body' or the 'outer box'. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code: you need to have a `margin: 0 auto`, and add `text-align:center`.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.box .box-inner {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 40px;
}

.btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 400;
}
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  color: #000000;
  outline: 0;
}

.me {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.me:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.cv {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.cv:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.rd {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.rd:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.av {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.av:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.rr {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.rr:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below CSS

```
.box
{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and modify you HTML too

```
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>myname</h1>
    <button class="btn me">me</button>
    <button class="btn cv">cv</button>
    <button class="btn rd">rd</button>
    <button class="btn av">av</button>
    <button class="btn rr">rr</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

this will place buttons in center of page, both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

check out this code: you need to have a `margin 0 auto`, and add `text-align:center`

```css
  html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.box .box-inner {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 40px;
}

.btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 400;
}
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  color: #000000;
  outline: 0;
}

.me {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.me:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.cv {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.cv:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.rd {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.rd:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.av {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.av:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}

.rr {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #000000;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.rr:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000 inset, 0 0 10px 4px #000000;
}
```

```html
        <body>
          <div class='box'>
            <div class='box-inner'>
                <h1>myname</h1>
                <button class="btn me">me</button>
                <button class="btn cv">cv</button>
                <button class="btn rd">rd</button>
                <button class="btn av">av</button>
                <button class="btn rr">rr</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
```